# get BitmapImage from Web URI

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7, bitmapimage

I have in my Windows Phone app several images that are binded to uri's this causes the UI threa to get blocked when all the images are downloaded. I cant create a bitmapImage instance on a different thread because I would get an "Invalid cross thread operation" exeption.

I tried downloading the image using a WebClient but there is no constructor that accepts a stream for BitmapImage.

Any thought as to how I can accomplish downloading images in the background?

thanks

Amit

Comment: Can you give an exmaple of the method you are using to download and bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a `Stream` to provide the content for a `BitmapImage` you create an instance using the default constructor then call `SetSource` passing the stream:-

```
  var bi = new BitmapImage();
  bi.SetSource(myStream);
```

However I think you may be re-inventing the wheel here.  Take a look the link below:-

[Keep a low profile (LowProfileImageLoader helps the Windows Phone 7 UI thread stay responsive by loading images in the background](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're still on the UI thread using WebClient. If you continue with that approach, you can also consider HttpWebRequest. Here's a working sample including resolution for the invalid cross-thread access exception.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)